# Long text in overpic

Tags: standalone, overpic

I want to write something over an image, so I'm using `overpic` package. However, my text is so long that it doesn't not fit because LaTeX keeps writing in the same line and it does not go to the next line when it reaches the limit of the picture, which I do not want. My document class is `standalone`. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{overpic}[scale = 0.5]{o1.png}
 \put(3,27){\color{red} some very very very long text that will not fit in the picture.}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Any solutions!!

Comment: `\put(3,27){\color{red}\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright some .....}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That worked!! Thanks a lot.